# YOLOv5 Not Detecting Custom Data

Tags: python, pytorch, object-detection, yolo, yolov5

I'm facing an issue with YOLOv5, where it's not detecting objects in custom data even after training. I've tried running it on both Python 3.9 and Python 3.10 with the same result.

`%cd yolov5/
!python train.py --img 416 --batch 16 --epochs 100 --data /content/yolov5/idk-1/data.yaml --weights yolov5s.pt --cache

!python detect.py --weights /content/yolov5/runs/train/exp/weights/best.pt --img 416 --source /content/yolov5/idk-1/train/images/1_jpeg.rf.6095f91252eee827890508b0eb7db4f5.jpg --conf 0.25`

However, the model is not detecting any objects in the image it was trained on. I expected it to detect objects that it was trained on.

Note:I m using google colab

Additional Information:

I have checked that my custom data is correctly labeled.
I verified that the paths to the data and weights are correct.
I have tried adjusting the confidence threshold (--conf) without success.
Any insights or suggestions on what might be causing this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

I have tried adjusting the confidence threshold (--conf) without success.
Any insights or suggestions on what might be causing this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

1. Test the model on the train data: check if it works properly. If it does get detections, by doing so, you can verify if your data has been properly annotated, which leads to second point.
2. Verify that your images have been annotated correctly. If this is also appropriate, then issue maybe with the difficulty of dataset itself.
3. It could be that the images you work with have objects of very small size, low resolution, or both. Then, you should apply some preprocessing techniques to deal with that, like super resolution. It is a common issue with *remote sensing*, for example. You might want to look for SuperYOLO for this, or increase image resolution with some generative techniques.